# SVN Continuous Integration Service Provider

Tags: c#, svn, continuous-integration

are there any continuous integration service/hosting providers that I can just point at an arbitrary SVN server (given credentials of course) and it'll update to the latest source and build?

I'm interested in building C# projects, ideally, it would be something like the TFS Build manager, or cruisecontrol.net ... though it doesn't have to be those products in particular.

Comment: You'll need to specify your type of project, language etc. You'll most likely need a build environment setup, so in most cases it's easier to host your own.

Comment: good point, modified the question to include my target build environment :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're looking at C# projects, have a look at [SourceAnvil](http://sourceanvil.net/). It's a beta at the moment, but you might be able to get involved. It's using [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/index.html), which I can recommend as easy to set up if you decide to host your own.

Comment: The SourceAnvil URL no longer seems to be working. I emailed them for more information and did not receive a response.  Looks like it's dead :-P

Comment: That's a shame, it looked like a very promising service!